# BASH: how to make timecode calculations

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I wish to know how to calculate the difference among two video timecodes tha are in frames (in this case, a second equals 30 frames).

Let say the point A is 600 (00:00:02) and the point B is 120 (00:00:04).

How can I calculate the difference among pont A and B and echo the result in the 00:00:00.00 format (h:m:s) using bash?

---

UPDATE:

This is perfection: http://www.1728.com/angle.htm

Comment: For command-line timecode conversion and arithmetic you may want to checkout the [timecode program](https://github.com/sshaw/Time-Timecode#timecode-utility-program).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the `export` statements are redundant since the current shell is expanding `$A` and `$B`.

To get those numbers from the timestamps, GNU `date` will help:

```
jinx:752 Z$ date -d 00:01:18.44 +%T.%N # to show that it works
00:01:18.440000000
jinx:753 Z$ date -d 00:01:18.44 +%s.%N
1299214878.440000000
```

Now you can do your calculations, then translate back at the end for display (as Edwin Buck said, don't try to store intermediate results in this format):

```
jinx:754 Z$ date -d @1299214878.44 +%T.%N
00:01:18.440000000
```

Comment: How can I use your suggestion if the input time is in frames and not in the time format? (in this case, 30 frames equals 1 second).

Comment: As I read the original question, you wee getting them in timestamps.  If you're getting them in frame counts then you can ignore the input conversion step, which gives you the next answer.

Answer (score 2):

Keep all of the times in "frames", then display the frame as a time through a single formatting routine.  If you attempt to convert to times, you'll make the mathematical conversions much harder (as time is a base 60 system).

```
frames2date () {
  local secs=$((2 * $1));
  date --utc --date "1970-01-01 ${secs} sec" "+%T"
}
```

should convert the number of frames into a time, note that you need to add years, months, and days if your times exceed 24 hours.

Comment: Fixed an issue with not properly escaping out the math in bash.

Comment: to call this `frames2date $(($B - $A))`

Comment: In this case, the timecode will always be inferior to 24 hours.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with the function for frames2date $((60)) is resulting 00:02:00 while 60 frames should result in 00:00:02 ...

Answer (score 0):

(Not Perfect) SOLUTION:

With the help of my friends, here's my complete bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#ffmpeg [inputfile] [starttimecode] [videoduration] [video details] [size] [audio details] [alltherest] [outputfile]

video=-'vcodec libx264 -vpre slower -crf 22'
size='-s 320x240'
audio='-acodec libmp3lame -aq 0 -ac 1'

in=$(date --utc --date "$3" +%s)
out=$(date --utc --date "$4" +%s)
dur=$(date --utc --date "1970-01-01 $[$out-$in] sec" "+%T")
ss=$(date --utc --date "1970-01-01 $[$in] sec" "+%T")

ffmpeg -i $1.$2 $video $size $audio -threads 0 -y $1.mp4

#ffmpeg -i t1.flv -ss 00:00:32 -t 00:00:04 -vcodec libx264 -vpre slower -crf 22 -s 320x240 -acodec libmp3lame -aq 0 -ac 1 -threads 0 -y t1.mp4
```

I saved the script as "v" and here's how I call it from cli:

```
v t1 flv 00:00:32.658 00:00:36.060
```

This way I can cut a part of a video file directly from ffmpeg cli. But the calculations among timecodes are not quite precise, so I need to work it on a little bit more to achieve this: http://www.1728.com/angle.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach not using the date tool:

```
    function timecode_to_int() {
      if [[ "$1" =~ ^((0*([0-9]+):)?0*([0-9]+):)?0*([0-9]+)(\.([0-9]{1,3}))? ]]; then
        VALUE=$((${BASH_REMATCH[5]}))
        [[ -n "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}" ]] && VALUE=$((${BASH_REMATCH[4]}*60+$VALUE))
        [[ -n "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" ]] && VALUE=$((${BASH_REMATCH[3]}*60*60+$VALUE))
        VALUE=$(($VALUE*1000))

        if [[ -n "${BASH_REMATCH[7]}" ]]; then
          VALUE=$(($VALUE+10#$(printf %-3s ${BASH_REMATCH[7]} | sed s_\ _0_g)))
        fi
        echo "${VALUE}"
      else
        echo "Invalid timecode '$1', aborting." >&2
        exit 1
      fi
    }

    function int_to_timecode() {
        MILLISECONDS="$(($1%1000))"
        SECS="$(($1/1000%60))"
        MINUTES="$(($1/1000/60%60))"
        HOURS="$(($1/1000/60/60))"

        if [[ $HOURS -ne 0 ]]; then
            printf "%d:%02d:%02d" $HOURS $MINUTES $SECS
        elif [[ $MINUTES -ne 0 ]]; then
            printf "%d:%02d" $MINUTES $SECS
        else
            printf "%d" $SECS
        fi
        if [[ ${MILLISECONDS} -ne 0 ]]; then
            printf ".%03d" $MILLISECONDS | sed s_0*\$__
        fi
    }

    # To answer your question completely:
    echo $(int_to_timecode $(($(timecode_to_int "00:00:04")-$(timecode_to_int "00:00:02"))))
```